# Clustering table on geohash index and geohash ordered table

Tags: postgis, performance, geohash

Could there be a performance gain by reorganizing the rows in a table by Geohash and then CLUSTERing this table on the Geohash index of the geometries?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptbl AS
SELECT *, (st_geohash(st_transform(geom,4326),10))as geohash
FROM mytable  ORDER BY geohash;

DELETE FROM  mytable;

ALTER TABLE tmptbl DROP COLUMN geohash;

INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM tmptbl;

DROP INDEX mytable _geom_gist;

CREATE INDEX mytable _geom_gist
ON mytable USING gist(geom);

CREATE INDEX mytable_geom_geohash
ON mytable  (st_geohash(st_transform(geom,4326),10));

CLUSTER mytable USING mytable_geom_geohash;
```

Comment: The most important thing your question is missing is how will you be using the database. Most performance tweaks make some thing perform better but other things perform worse.

Comment: For me, spatial index speeds up spatial request and geohash ordering speeds up sequential read of the table for a given zoom.

Comment: I'm interested in increasing reactivity of my clients app (QGIS and GEOSERVER).